# Export SQLite Data to SD Card - File Not Found Exception

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get SQLite Internal Storage Data to SD Card, but everytime i am getting File Not Found Exception.

This is the class, which i am using to get data and then store to SD Card, check below:

**MainActivity.java** is the only class i am using in my program to get data.

```
package com.export.data;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnGetData);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                InputStream myInput;
                try {
                    myInput = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.example.parsingsqlite/databases/storeJSON.db");//this is
                    // Set the output folder on the SDcard
                    File directory = new File("/sdcard/Hello");
                    // Create the folder if it doesn't exist:
                    if (!directory.exists()) 
                    {
                        directory.mkdirs();
                    } 
                    // Set the output file stream up:

                    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(directory.getPath()+"/storeJSON.db");

                    // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0)
                    {
                        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    // Close and clear the streams
                    myOutput.flush();

                    myOutput.close();

                    myInput.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IOException", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Backup Done Succesfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Note:** If i use same code in same application whose data want to retrieve then getting, but if trying to get data from another application by doing tap on button then getting FileNotFound Exception. (like doing now)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution try once

```
 File f=new File("/data/data/com.example.parsingsqlite/databases/storeJSON.db");
                    FileInputStream fis=null;
                    FileOutputStream fos=null;

                    try
                    {
                      fis=new FileInputStream(f);
                      fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Hello/storeJSON.db");
                      while(true)
                      {
                        int i=fis.read();
                        if(i!=-1)
                        {fos.write(i);}
                        else
                        {break;}
                      }
                      fos.flush();
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "DB dump OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "DB dump ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                      try
                      {
                        fos.close();
                        fis.close();
                      }
                      catch(Exception ioe)
                      {}
                    }
```

and do not forget to add below `permission` in your `manifest.xml` file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: getting - DB dump Error

Comment: That means  `No Database ` created on  `/data/data/com.example.parsingsqlite/databases/ ` path check it carefully

Comment: actually i am using two different applications, one to store data to database and second to get data into sd card, if i use my above code in first app (where i am storing data into SQLite then able to get data into SD Card, in this app i have DBHelper class) but when i use second app to get data into SD Card getting FileNotFound (this app only has MainActivity, which i posted above) I hope now you got my point

Answer (score 0):

Try below method:

```
    public void backup() {
    try {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File outputFile = new File(sdcard, "MyAppDb.bak");

        if (!outputFile.exists()) 
             outputFile.createNewFile(); 

        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        File inputFile = new File(data,
                "data/com.example.myapp/databases/myappdb.sqlite");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //throw new Error("Copying Failed");
    }
}
```